# Reconstruct Quartics from roots

Tags: calculus, polynomials, roots

Not sure how to reconstruct an equation from roots. The roots are $-1/2, 1/2, 2, 3$ and the equation is $4x^4-20x^3+23x^2+5x-6.$

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: Are you looking for the general method?

Comment: This is not clear.  If you have the four roots, $r_1,r_2,r_3,r_4$ then the polynomial is $C(x-r_1)(x-r_2)(x-r_3)(x-r_4)$ for some non-zero constant $C$.  Can't say more without more information.

Answer (score 2):

Let us say an equation has roots ($a_1,a_2,...a_k$)

Then, the polynomial must be of the form $(x-a_1)(x-a_2)...(x-a_k)$

Simply multiply and expand to get $(x-\frac{1}{2})(x+\frac{1}{2})(x-2)(x-3)=0$

By multiplying both sides by 4 we get $(2x-1)(2x+1)(x-2)(x-3)=0$ which expands to give
$4x^4−20x^3+23x^2+5x−6= 0$